# Icinga2 disk check - suppressing testing for some dirs

Tags: linux, debian, icinga, icinga2

Certain app creates a directory that a root cannot access (see [Getting info about a weird directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/940329/getting-info-about-a-weird-directory)) and Icinga2 instance running on that host creates useless alerts about it:

```
disk on homehost.dom is CRITICAL!

Info:    DISK CRITICAL - /tmp/.mount_JoplinuOkeCu is not accessible: Permission denied
```

How do I suppress the check for `/tmp` directory only in Icinga2 / the disk plugin?

Object details:

```
Object 'homehost.dom!disk' of type 'Service':
  % declared in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 66:1-66:53
  * __name = "homehost.dom!disk"
  * action_url = ""
  * check_command = "disk"
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 69:3-69:24
  * check_interval = 60
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/templates.conf', lines 28:3-28:21
  * check_period = ""
  * check_timeout = null
  * command_endpoint = ""
  * display_name = "disk"
  * enable_active_checks = true
  * enable_event_handler = true
  * enable_flapping = false
  * enable_notifications = true
  * enable_passive_checks = true
  * enable_perfdata = true
  * event_command = ""
  * flapping_threshold = 0
  * flapping_threshold_high = 30
  * flapping_threshold_low = 25
  * groups = [ ]
  * host_name = "homehost.dom"
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 66:1-66:53
  * icon_image = ""
  * icon_image_alt = ""
  * max_check_attempts = 5
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/templates.conf', lines 27:3-27:24
  * name = "disk"
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 66:1-66:53
  * notes = ""
  * notes_url = ""
  * package = "_etc"
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 66:1-66:53
  * retry_interval = 30
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/templates.conf', lines 29:3-29:22
  * source_location
    * first_column = 1
    * first_line = 66
    * last_column = 53
    * last_line = 66
    * path = "/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf"
  * templates = [ "disk", "generic-service" ]
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 66:1-66:53
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/templates.conf', lines 26:1-26:34
  * type = "Service"
  * vars
    % = modified in '/etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf', lines 71:3-71:16
  * volatile = false
  * zone = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to exclude based on path and fstype.

Please see:

- https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_disk.html
- https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/10-icinga-template-library/#disk